# Hide element on based on author role of the post

Tags: php, css, elementor

What I need : (IF post is made by author is in X role, display this, else display this)

Am using elementor and Jetengine.  I need to be able to hide element on a page base the query.

What am thinking is give a CSS class to element I want to hide and call that class with php.
I have no idea on how to achieve this.

```
$current_author_roles = get_the_author_meta('roles');
if ( in_array('Adminstrator', $current_author_roles) ) {
}
```

CLASS:

```
<style> 
.hidden{ 
    display:block; 
} 
.hidden{ 
    display:none; 
} 
.shown{ 
    display: block !important; 
} 
</style>
```

Comment: An element with CSS property `display:none` is still loaded when page loads, and can be viewed in page source. Your should extract it from back end

Comment: thanks for your answer. for what I need to do just hide with display:none is ok at least for now.

Comment: did you post a jquery code?